# PHP Search systems - how to use LIKE

Tags: php, search

The following code fetches the TITLE attribute for each post. I want to compare it to a search phrase $f using something similar to the way LIKE works with SQL.

```
<?php 

$terms = $_GET['f'];

$searchs = get_posts($args);

foreach($searchs as $search){

    $title = get_the_title($search);
```

Then we would need something like:

```
if($title is LIKE $f) {   }
```

How would it work?

Comment: What do you mean by "LIKE"? How do you fetch the posts inside `posts`? If you need to filter large amounts of data, it is much more effective to do that within the database queries than inside a PHP script.

Comment: It's a [MySQL thing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-like-mysql.aspx).

Comment: This looks like not a wise idea, as you might pay a price for fetching all posts. Do you have a database?

Comment: @jsalonen I think he means "something similar to the way the `LIKE` keyword works in a condition in MySQL". Like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE somecol LIKE '%some value%'`

Comment: I think he would like to search a string in the same manner that is done using the `LIKE` in a mysql query.

Comment: Why is everyone saying LIKE is MySQL? It's a standard SQL feature implemented pretty much identically in every SQL-based DBMS I've come across. (Except for collation issues: in MS SQL Server, for instance, it is case insensitive, whereas Postgres provides a separate "ILIKE" operator if you want that behaviour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LIKE is a MySQL keyword, you have to use that in an SQL statement like so:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%keyword%';
```

If you want to do your search using PHP, you can use strpos like so:

```
if(strpos($title, $keyword) !== FALSE) {   }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the way you word this, I presume it cannot be done in the database with an actual LIKE or full-text search. I think what you're probably after is Regular Expressions, which are a little more advanced than the pattern matching provided by the SQL "LIKE" operator, but can be used for the same purpose.

PHP integrates the "Perl Compatible Regular Expressions" library. Have a look here: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php or look for introductions to standard regular expression syntax online.

As a simple case, you might want to do this:

```
// Compose your matching pattern
// Be sure to escape user-supplied parts
// ".*" is roughly equivalent to "%" in LIKE
// the "/i" modifier means "case insensitive"
$pattern = '/.*' . preg_quote($_GET['f']) . '.*/i';

$searches = get_posts($args);

foreach($searches as $search)
{
    $title = get_the_title($search);

    if ( preg_match($pattern, $title) )
    {
        # FOUND A MATCH!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to lookup [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) or PostgreSQL [full text search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search). `LIKE` isn't what you want if you plan on doing "fuzzy" searches or need more power than simple string comparisons.